# How do i use jquery Datatable plugin in gridviews present in different jquery ui tabs?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using jquery datatable plugin in a gridview present in a jquery ui tabs. My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
            var gv = $('.display');
            var thead = $('<thead/>');
            thead.append(gv.find('tr:eq(0)'));
            gv.append(thead);
            gv.dataTable({
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "iDisplayLength": 10,
                "aaSorting": [],
                "bDestroy": true,
                "bRetrieve": true,
                'bProcessing': true,
                'bServerSide': false
            });

            ApplyDataTable('.display');
        });
```

I am using `class="display"` in the gridview to apply datatable plugin on it and this plugin is working fine for me in case of one gridview in any ui tab.

There are 3 gridviews present in 3 different tabs.When i apply `class="display"` on other gridviews the heador row of the gridviews becomes triple showing header rows of all the three gridviews in all gridviews.How do i solve this problem and use this plugin in all my gridviews ?.

Comment: can you show in a fiddle,so its easy to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** using  class `.display`  makes every grid with that class to append so,every time it runs, append to current grid and appends previous grids as well.

`ApplyDataTable('.display')` Apply to all grid with `.display` class

Solutions Use Id="" ie `$('#grid1')` instead of `$('.display')`

Or Use

```
           thead.html(gv.find('tr:eq(0)'));
           gv.html(thead);
```

Instead Of

```
           thead.append(gv.find('tr:eq(0)'));
           gv.append(thead);
```

Answer (score 1):

1- For the header part, you should separate the treatment of each instance :

```
$('.display').each(function(){
    var tbl = $(this);
    var thead = $('<thead/>');
    thead.append(tbl.find('tr:eq(0)'));
    tbl.append(thead);
});
```

2- Calling `$('.display').dataTable({ options })` is equivalent to `$('.display').each(function({ $(this).dataTable({ options }); });`

3- Depending on what `ApplyDataTable`, you may need to move this call inside the `.each` loop.